# Flutter/Dart programmatically unicode string

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode, icons

I have a list of customized icons to my app, it comes like below setted as IconData, note `codePoint` (0xe931).

```dart
IconData angry_face = IconData(0xe931, fontFamily: _fontFamily);
```

There's nothing wrong with that, but I've some cases where I need this icon as Unicode string to be used as a text. It should be done just like:

```dart
// It works too
Text('\ue931', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: _fontFamily));
```

The problem is:

I don't wanna use this code "by hand" because this icons are changed constantly by designers team and sometimes it changes its code messing up my app icons. What I need to do is get the icon object and parse it to the Unicode string, so I can use it with a Text widget.

I thought that would work to get programmatically that code and just use it, but it don't:

```dart
var iconcode = iconData.codePoint.toRadixString(16);

var result;

// Error: An escape sequence starting with '\u'
// must be followed by 4 hexadecimal digits or
// from 1 to 6 digits between '{' and '}'
result = '\u$iconcode';

// Just a simple string
result = '\\u$iconcode';
```

In few words: How can I parse programmatically int codePoint to a valid Unicode string?

Comment: Try: `final result = String.fromCharCode(iconData.codePoint);`

Comment: That's right, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the right answer. I tried everything but this... Thank you @julemand101

```dart
final result = String.fromCharCode(iconData.codePoint);
```